# How to get data between two date string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have over 8 billion data in big query and it has a cloumn named EdgeEndTimestamp and its type is STRING. I dived into documentation, and I can not find a way to get data according to this field.

for example I want to get all data between `2021-06-01T20:45:00.104Z` and `2021-06-01T21:15:00.104Z`
Timestamp of EdgeEndTimestamp is like `2022-07-25T11:07:15Z`

Since there is too much data in there what would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to a timestamp with `TIMESTAMP()` and use it in the `WHERE` clause.

Example:

```sql
WITH your_table AS 
(
  SELECT '2021-06-01T20:45:00.104Z' AS dt, 123 AS val
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2021-06-01T21:15:00.104Z', 456
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2021-06-01T21:45:00.104Z', 789
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE TIMESTAMP(dt) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2021-06-01T20:45:00.104Z') AND TIMESTAMP('2021-06-01T21:15:00.104Z')
```

Comment: what does this part do?: `SELECT '2021-06-01T20:45:00.104Z' AS dt, 123 AS val
  UNION ALL `

Comment: It is an example for a table since you did not provide one, and it creates a table named `your_table` so that the query in my example works when you run it. You will be using only the part from `SELECT *` onwards and replacing `your_table` with your actual table.